# Why are my list controls being cleared after being populated in WizardStep0 in an ASP.NET Wizard control?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using a Wizard control in an ASP.NET application. In several of the WizardSteps, I'm populating a DropDownList and a CheckBoxList in the Activate event of the step. This works correctly in all steps except WizardStep0. What's happening is that the code is running to populate the lists, but once rendering is complete on WizardStep0, the list controls are empty, as if they've been cleared.

Here's the `WizardStep0_Activate` method:

```
protected void WizardStep0_Activate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //Initialize dropdowns
  PopulateRelationList(ddlRelation);
  PopulateGuardianshipTypeList();
} //end method WizardStep0_Activate
```

Here are the two methods called in `WizardStep0_Activate` (the method `BindSelectionListLocalized` works elsewhere, so I know the problem isn't there):

```
protected void PopulateRelationList(DropDownList ddlist)
{
  //First, clear the list
  ddlist.Items.Clear();
  string valueField = "RelationID";
  string textField = "Relation";
  string query = "SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar(2), RelationID) AS RelationID, Relation FROM tlkRelation WHERE Lang ='" + lang + "'";
  DBFunctions.BindSelectionListLocalized(query, textField, valueField, ddlist, GetGlobalResourceObject("LocalizedText", "selectDDL").ToString());
} //end method PopulateRelationList

protected void PopulateGuardianshipTypeList()
{
  //First, clear the list
  cblGuardianshipType.Items.Clear();
  string valueField = "GuardianshipType";
  string textField = "TypeDescr";
  string query = "SELECT GuardianshipType, TypeDescr FROM tlkGuardianshipTypes WHERE Lang = '" + lang + "'";
  DBFunctions.BindSelectionListLocalized(query, textField, valueField, cblGuardianshipType, null);
}
```

Here's what I'm getting (just the two list controls mentioned above) - the "Type of Guardianship Requested" should have a CheckBoxList with four items next to it; the "Relation to Client" DropDownList should have several choices:

[image: unpopulated list controls]

The most important information is that the same code works correctly in the Activate events for all subsequent WizardSteps, just not for WizardStep0. When I run this in the debugger, WizardStep0_Activate is firing, and the methods to populate the list controls are running; the offending controls are somehow being cleared afterwards, when the page is rendered.

Comment: You have defined `ddlRelation` in the argument list of `PopulateRelationList` without a type, and it is not used. A typo?

Comment: It was a typo - corrected.

Comment: If you move to Step1 and then go back to step 0, does it work?

Comment: @DeadZone: Yes, as a matter of fact it does.

Comment: I think you may have a [page lifecycle](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/73728/ASP-NET-Application-and-Page-Life-Cycle) issue.  Something when the page is initially loaded (and wizard step 0 loads up) is different than when you switch between steps.  There's not enough information to know this for sure, but the symptoms look like that.

Comment: I figured it was something like that. But how do I begin to suss it out?

Comment: OK, so I moved the list control populators to the `WizardStep0_PreRender` event (inside a test for postback), which seems to have fixed the problem. Now I'm wondering if it wouldn't be more correct to do the same for all the other WizardSteps (even though WizardStep0 appears to be the only one with the problem).